# ANTLR Custom DOT Template

Tags: tree, antlr, dot, stringtemplate, abstract-syntax-tree

Is there a way to create/extend the default template for generating .dot files in ANTLR?

I have some custom properties in my nodes that I'd like to visualise on my tree, rather than having to print them out to a console each time.

I only have a basic working knowledge of StringTemplate (V3) at the moment.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is:

- extend `DOTTreeGenerator` and change the (static) node-template in the constructor
- override its `getNodeST` and add your custom attribute(s) to the template

A demo that shows how to add the child count of each tree:

```
// Original source of DOTTreeGenerator: 
// https://github.com/antlr/antlr3/blob/master/runtime/Java/src/main/java/org/antlr/runtime/tree/DOTTreeGenerator.java
class MyDOTTreeGenerator extends DOTTreeGenerator {

    public MyDOTTreeGenerator() {
        // added ", childCount=$childCount$"
        DOTTreeGenerator._nodeST = new StringTemplate("$name$ [label=\"text=$text$, childCount=$childCount$\"];\n");
    }

    @Override
    protected StringTemplate getNodeST(TreeAdaptor adaptor, Object t) {

        // cast "t" to your own tree implementation
        CommonTree tree = (CommonTree)t;
        String text = adaptor.getText(t);
        StringTemplate nodeST = _nodeST.getInstanceOf();
        String uniqueName = "n"+getNodeNumber(t);
        nodeST.setAttribute("name", uniqueName);

        // set the "childCount" attribute 
        nodeST.setAttribute("childCount", tree.getChildCount());
        nodeST.setAttribute("text", fixString(text));
        return nodeST;
    }
}
```

Use it like this:

```
TLexer lexer = new TLexer(new ANTLRStringStream("..."));
TParser parser = new TParser(new CommonTokenStream(lexer));
CommonTree root = parser...
MyDOTTreeGenerator gen = new MyDOTTreeGenerator();
System.out.println(gen.toDOT(root));
```

Comment: Thanks Bart. However I'm using C# and the corresponding C# class doesn't have any of the fields that the Java version has. Weird.

Comment: Then I suggest you look at the [C# source code](https://github.com/antlr/antlr3/blob/master/runtime/CSharp3/Sources/Antlr3.Runtime/Tree/DotTreeGenerator.cs) for `DotTreeGenerator` and make changes accordingly.